# How to automatically attribute links with nofollow, only for a SPECIFIC html element in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, nofollow

Some time ago I found this good old No Follow script, to add a nofollow attribute to hyperlinks. However, I dont want this script to be a site-wide thing! I just want hyperlinks inside a certain html element (say for example `<article> ...</article>`) to be attributed with a nofollow. How can one adapt the below script to achieve this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var a = $(this);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[href^='https://']").each(function (){
            if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
                $(this).attr('rel', 'nofollow');
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

---

*Note: in essence, my question is the exact opposite of this question:*
"[Nofollow for the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575290/nofollow-for-the-whole-page)"

Comment: Amend the selector, from `$('a[href^=...]')` to `$('article a[href^=...]')`? Or, within the `each()` method and in the `if` statement, check that the `<a>` element has an ancestor of the particular type, for example: `if ($(this).parents('article').length && this.href...)`?

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas ! Beautiful! Please put your first suggestion to change from $("a[href^=...]") to $("article a[href^=...]") as answer so I can upvote and accept it! Cheers!